# Как в Bootstrap 4 добавить на показ 7 слайдов?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, bootstrap

Задача:
Показать 7 элементов. Если их будет больше. то показать стрелочку. Если меньше - не надо

Я вроде бы сделал, но при пролистывании вперед/назад скрывается/показывается 2 item'a.

Ссылка на код - http://www.codeply.com/go/gseMYHTCBF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для создание каруселей, а не слайдеров лучше использовать что другое кроме встроенного в bootstrap плагина, например я в своих проектах использую [owlcarousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)